# Area moments of a Freeman chain contour

Tags: geometry, area, polygons, image-processing, centroid

The area moments of a polygon can be computed by generalizations of the shoelace formula for area.

In particular, the first and second order moments are given by 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Centroid and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area#Any_polygon.

I was wondering if there are simplified forms when the polygon is described by a Freeman chain (so that the coordinates vary by at most one unit from vertex to vertex).

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem as follows. First, I need an analytic expression for an arbitrary polygon. Say that you have $n$ elements of length $S_k$ and angles $\Phi_k$ Then you can express the polygon in the complex plane with the fractal linkage (*Gnomon: from Pharoahs to fractals*, Michael J. Gazal$\acute{\text{e}}$, Princeton University Press, 1999) , that is

$$z=\text{cum}\sum_{k=1}^n S_ke^{i\Phi_k}$$

The perimeter, area, and centroid are given by

$$
s=\int |\dot z| du\\
A = {\textstyle{1 \over 2}}\int {\Im\left\{ {{z^{_*}}\dot z} \right\}} \,du\\\
z\left( G \right) = \frac{{\int {z\Im\left\{ {{z^{_*}}\dot z} \right\}} \,du}}{{3A}}\
$$

Zwikker, C. (1968) [*The Advanced Geometry of Plane Curves and Their Applications*, Dover Press] gives the derivations for the following moments:

$$
\text{Polar inertia}\\
J_0=\frac{1}{4}\int zz^{_*} {\Im\left\{ {{z^{_*}}\dot z} \right\}} du\\
\text{Binet's inertia moments}\\
J_x=\frac{1}{4}\int x^2 {\Im\left\{ {{z^{_*}}\dot z} \right\}} du\\
J_y=\frac{1}{4}\int y^2 {\Im\left\{ {{z^{_*}}\dot z} \right\}} du\\
\text{Centrifigal inertia moment}\\
J_{xy}=\frac{1}{4}\int xy {\Im\left\{ {{z^{_*}}\dot z} \right\}} du\\
$$

Notice that $J_0=J_x+J_y$.

At least, that's what I would do.

Comment: Thank you for this input, Cye. I do have the formulas for a polygon (see the links). What I am after is the specialization for the case of a Freeman chain. In fact, a micro-optimization.